# Extract several ints from string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string similar to the following:

`"01Jan00 20:07:16#[AA] :Test aaa - ExOne: 2264 ms, ExTwo:  8988 ms, ExThree: 14252 ms, Avg Ex (x100): 3229"`

I am trying to get the 4 values (ExOne, ExTwo, ExThree, Avg Ex) from this string either using regex or by splitting the string by ':' and parsing the values from that. I am newer with regex so here was my attempt:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"ExOne: (?<exOne>\d+).((?<= ExTwo:)(.*?<exTwo>)(?= ms)).(?<exThree>\d+).((?<=\:.).(?<avgEx>\d+))");
```

If I use `ExOne: (?<exOne>\d+)` itself I get 2264 which is the value I need. What I have been trying to do is use look ahead after getting that first value to skip to the second value and put it in a grouping.

Comment: `I am trying to get the values from this string` Which values? Where is the expected output?

Comment: Maybe [`\b\d+(?=\s*ms\b|$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%5cs*ms%5cb%7c%24)&i=01Jan00+20%3a07%3a16%23%5bAA%5d+%3aTest+aaa+-+ExOne%3a+2264+ms%2c+ExTwo%3a++8988+ms%2c+ExThree%3a+14252+ms%2c+Avg+Ex+(x100)%3a+3229)? Or [`(?:Avg\s*Ex\s*\(x\d+\)|Ex(?:One|Two|Three)):\s*(\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3aAvg%5cs*Ex%5cs*%5c(x%5cd%2b%5c)%7cEx(%3f%3aOne%7cTwo%7cThree))%3a%5cs*(%5cd%2b)&i=01Jan00+20%3a07%3a16%23%5bAA%5d+%3aTest+aaa+-+ExOne%3a+2264+ms%2c+ExTwo%3a++8988+ms%2c+ExThree%3a+14252+ms%2c+Avg+Ex+(x100)%3a+3229)?

Comment: Thanks for your help @stribizhev the first expression worked

Comment: If I post my solution, will you accept it?

Comment: Posted and added explanations. Please consider upvoting if it is helpful and accepting since it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
\b\d+(?=\s*ms\b|$)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5Cd%2B(%3F%3D%5Cs%2Ams%5Cb%7C%24)&i=01Jan00%2020%3A07%3A16%23%5BAA%5D%20%3ATest%20aaa%20-%20ExOne%3A%202264%20ms%2C%20ExTwo%3A%20%208988%20ms%2C%20ExThree%3A%2014252%20ms%2C%20Avg%20Ex%20(x100)%3A%203229)

The regex matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d+` -  1 or more digits
- `(?=\s*ms\b|$)` - then checks if there are 0 or more whitespace symbols, followed by `ms` as a whole word, or just end of string.

C# code:

```
var txt = "01Jan00 20:07:16#[AA] :Test aaa - ExOne: 2264 ms, ExTwo:  8988 ms, ExThree: 14252 ms, Avg Ex (x100): 3229";
var result = Regex.Matches(txt, @"\b\d+(?=\s*ms\b|$)").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, it will give you 4 matches with numbers in separate groups: `(\w+:\s+(\d+)\sms,)|([\w\s]+\s\(\w+\):\s(\d+))`